# Why does the row id (_id) for Instances table change?

Tags: android, calendar

I'm building an app for Android where I'm reading the instances table to get all events.

I've used the "unique" row id as a way to reference to different instances, however I've now found that the row id changes over time, it actually seems to increment by 2 every now and then. Is there a reason for this behaviour? What is the recommended way to handle instances and how to uniquely reference each instance?

This is the only code I use when creating the meeting objects in the app.

```
int columnID = cursor.getColumnIndex(CalendarContract.Instances._ID);
String uniqueid = cursor.getString(columnID);
meeting.setUniqueId(uniqueid);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be using `CalendarContract.Instances.EVENT_ID` instead as the documentation describes that as the unique ID for events: [EVENT_ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Instances.html#EVENT_ID)

_ID might be changing because they are adding/removing rows under the hood without caring for the changes.